# Installing Win7 over PXE through Serva fails - FAILED/ABORT

Tags: windows-7, installation, pxe

I am trying to install Windows 7 over PXE with Serva on my new gaming build. Once I get past the installation menu another window pops up reading "loading network resources". After a couple of seconds the message changes to "loading network resources. FAILED/ABORT". I have checked all over the web and found out that I need to put my motherboard LAN drivers in the SERVA ROOT driver folder, however it still wont work (but it does install the drivers but at the end I recieve FAILED/ABORT again).

My motherboard is: ASUS Maximus Vi Hero. Just as a side note, when I check the LAN driver list for my motherboard I get a list with over 10 different drivers and don't quite know which one to put in the SERVA folder.

Answer (score 0):

Read Serva documentation; it's all about adding the right driver in the right place.

Remember if you are installing a 32bit OS you must "only" add the 32 bit version of the driver, the same if you are installing a 64 bit OSs; do not mix different architecture drivers.